# Code to strip html comments in Notepad++ and leave only code

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

I would like to strip HTML comments in Notepad++ and leave only code in an html file. How do I go about this? I can use regular expression search/replace.

Answer (score 10):

I would use

```
<!--([^-]|-[^-])*-->
```

which is more robust (less permissive) than Oscar's solution.

Answer (score 2):

After searching I couldn't find a simple solution , but then i created one that i would like to share.

in Select "Regular Expression" - Replace With field empty like this

[image]

and that's it!. You need to carefully and inspect before and after so, not to loose actual code.I did not loose any code.

i hope it helps

Comment: +1 you know that you can embed screenshots in your answer right? ;)